# Solve the upper bound of the integral for arccosine

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

The function arccosine can defined as

$$\arccos(x) = \int_{1}^{x} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Let $\theta$ be a known angle such that

$$\theta = \int_{1}^{x} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Is it possible to solve for the upper bound $x$ in the second integral?

Comment: @PeterForeman solve for x, is there a method for that?

Comment: @PeterForeman I edited. I want to find the inverse by solving the upper bound $x$ of the definite integral. I wonder if it's possible. Matlab does it.

Comment: @eigenslacker could you give an example of the kind of output you are talking about?

Comment: Well, the inverse is just  the restriction of $\cos$ to the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @PeterForeman you are right. I edited the post as it made no sense.

Comment: Isn't the answer to the revised question just $x = \cos \theta$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes but I want to solve for $\cos(\theta)$ numerically.

Comment: @eigenslacker So you want to use the integral to try and numerically approximate ${\cos(\theta)}$? Is this the end goal?

Comment: Yes @Riemann'sPointyNose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so from the comment section what you actually are trying to do is approximate the value of ${\cos(\theta)}$ by using the integral ${\theta=-\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt}$. As you know, rearranging for ${x}$ gives

$${x=\cos(\theta)}$$

In all honesty, the best way of approximating ${\cos(\theta)}$ is probably to just use a Taylor Series (there are probably more advanced methods out there, but eh - the Taylor Series is a simple elementary approach, and should give you a fairly good approximation quite quickly).

If you want to use this integral though, a simple algorithmic approach would be to vary ${x}$ up and down, and approximate the integral using area approximation methods. You want to essentially find the ${x}$ that gives you the area closest to ${\theta}$. For example, if ${\theta}$ was ${0.5}$, then

$${-\int_{1}^{0.8}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\approx 0.64...}$$

So we increase ${x}$ a little bit (since this is above ${0.5}$):

$${-\int_{1}^{0.9}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\approx 0.451...}$$

So we decrease ${x}$ a little....

$${-\int_{1}^{0.85}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\approx 0.554...}$$

Then increase again, then decrease, etc etc etc. You see the pattern. Provided your method of approximating the area is good enough, eventually you should get a value that is closer and closer to the *true* value of ${x}$, and thus get a value for ${x=\cos(\theta)}$. Note that ${\cos(0.5)\approx 0.877...}$ so you can see this was getting us closer and closer.

It is really very, *very* dependant though on how good your area approximations are. I'm sure there are probably ways to speed this method up and make it fancier, but this is just a base method using the integral. Like I said - for any serious ${\cos}$ function calculating though, you want to use the Taylor Series.